# How to create a windows service that runs every day at 10:00 AM and 10:00 PM

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application

I need to create a Windows service or console application that is run at 10:00 AM and 10:00 PM every day.

Can someone help me how to best approach this issue?

Comment: When I need to do this, I create a Console application that never dies (just add Console.ReadLine() to the end) and run it on the System user. There are probably more robust solutions, but this is a simple way to do it. I'm not sure what "all the day 10:00 am and 10:00 pm" means, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Windows Task Scheduler to run an application at regular intervals.